# How can I get specific rows of a tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have several tensors:

logits: This tensor contains the final prediction scores.

```
tf.Tensor 'MemN2N_1/MatMul_3:0' shape=(?, 18230) dtype=float32
```

The final prediction is computed as predicted_op = tf.argmax(logits, 1, name="predict_op")

Now I want to restrict the prediction into some specific columns. The following two tensors contains column indices I want to choose from.

self._stories is of type

```
tf.Tensor 'stories:0' shape=(?, 12, 110) dtype=int32
```

self._queries is of type

```
tf.Tensor 'queries:0' shape=(?, 110) dtype=int32
```

Here the 110 columns are the index numbers I want to restrict logits into. For example, if logits = [[10,20,30,40,50], [10,20,30,40,50]..] and self._stories = [[[1,4,...], [1,2,4,...],...], [[0,4,...],[2,4...],...]...] and self._queries = [[1,4...],[2,4,...],...] then logits should look like [[20,30,50],[10,30,50]...]

How can I do this kind of index filtering in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out `tf.equal`? This compares two tensors and creates a new tensor containing True where equal, and False where not equal.

With this bool-tensor you feed `tf.select`, which choses from one tensor or another, element-wise, depending on the bool-value you created in step one.

Didn't look deeply into the particular shapes you provided, but with those two ops you can create the kind of flow you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#squeeze).

```py
row_indices = [1]
row = tf.gather(tf.constant([[1, 2],[3, 4]]), row_indices)
tf.Session().run(row)  # returns [[3, 4]]
```

You can remove the leading dimension of size 1 using [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#squeeze):

```
row = tf.squeeze(row, squeeze_dims=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`tf.slice(input_, begin, size, name=None)`.
See the TensorFlow documentation for more details:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice

Comment: hi, please can you provide context around the link, in case it ever breaks? thank you!